# Laravel update work without updating database

Tags: laravel

I work with Laravel API version 10 the post and get method is ok but the put method return success without updating the database I look for everything in the web to solve this solution with no issue.

I try to use `update()` and `save()`  I verify my model and table I try many solutions no way.

I use postman.

[image: postman put response]

### This is my model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class drivercard extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'drivercard';
    //match the columns in your table
    protected $fillable = [
        'Id', 
        'FirstName', 
        'LastName',
        'NIC',
        'IDCard',
        'EntrepriseNameAR',
        'EntrepriseNameEN',
        'IDEntreprise',
        'DateStart',
        'DateEnd',
        'Activity',
        'Category',
        'FirstNameEn',
        'LastNameEn',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'    
    ];

    protected $casts = [

        'Id'               => 'integer', 
        'FirstName'        => 'string',
        'LastName'         => 'string',
        'NIC'              => 'string',
        'IDCard'           => 'string',
        'EntrepriseNameAR' => 'string',
        'EntrepriseNameEN' => 'string',
        'IDEntreprise'     => 'string',
        'DateStart'        => 'string',
        'DateEnd'          => 'string',
        'Activity'         => 'string',
        'Category'         => 'string',
        'FirstNameEn'      => 'string', 
        'LastNameEn'       => 'string',
        'created_at'       => 'string',
        'updated_at'       => 'string'
    ];
    
}


----------
this my api
-----------

Route::put('/drivercard/{id}', [DriverCardController::class, "change"]);

----------
this is my update function in controller
----------
public function change(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        // DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
                $card = drivercard::find($id);
               // $card = drivercard::find($id)->update($request->all());
           
            if ($card) {

                // Update the model with the new data from the request
                $card->fill($request->all());
                
                //$card->FirstName = $request->FirstName;
                // $card->fill(['FirstName' => 'Amsterdam to Frankfurt']);
                //$card->update($request->all());
                
                // $card->update([
                   
                //         'updated_at' => now()
                    
                // ]);
                
                if ($card->save()) {
                    // Changes have been made, save the updated data
                    
            
                    // You can also do additional actions if needed
                    // ...
            
                   return response()->json(['message' => 'Card updated successfully','StatusCode' => '1000','res' => $card], 200);

                } else {
                    // No changes have been made
                    return response()->json(['message' => 'No changes detected']);
                }
               
                // Commit the transaction before returning
                // DB::commit();
                // Optionally, you can return a JSON response indicating success
            } else {
                // Rollback the transaction if the card is not found
                // DB::rollBack();
                // Return an error response if the card with the given ID is not found
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Card not found'], 404);
            } 
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // DB::rollBack();
            \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::error($e->getMessage());
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Internal Server Error'], 500);
        }            
         // $card->update($request->all());
            // $card->save();
            //return response()->json($request->all(), 200);                
         //return $card;

        //  $data = $request->validate([
        //     'FirstName' => 'string',
        //     // Add more validation rules as needed
        // ]);

        // $record = drivercard::find($id);

        // if (!$record) {
        //     return response()->json(['error' => 'card not found'], 404);
        // }

        // $record->updated_at = $request['updated_at'];
        // $record->LastName = $request['LastName'];
        // Manually set the timestamps
        // $record->update($request + ['updated_at' => now()]);
        // Save the model
        // $record->save();

        // Update the record with the validated data
        // $record->update($request->all());

        // Update fields manually
        // $result = DB::table('drivercard')
        // ->where('Id', $id)
        // ->update($request);

        // if ($result) {
        //     $record = DriverCard::find($id);
        //     return response()->json($record, 200);
        // } else {
        //     return response()->json(['error' => 'Update failed'], 500);
        // }

        
    }
```

Comment: try to comment out casts and send the req again. Why do u have  'created_at'       => 'string',
        'updated_at'       => 'string' as strings not datetimes?

Comment: @ftm I change this no way

Comment: Also remove 'created_at',
        'updated_at'    from fillable

Comment: I try this not working

Comment: does your response json have your updated fields?

Comment: yes i have succes 200 response and all data updated but when i check the database nothing is update

Comment: at that point the issue is more likely on the DB than your code. check what DB you are using, maybe you are looking on the wrong DB

Comment: yes the same  ok

Answer (score 0):

I not find any solution just I use mysqli for my case :

```
public function change(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        try {
                    $mysqli = DB::connection()->getPdo();

                    // Sanitize input data to prevent SQL injection
                    $FirstName          = $mysqli->quote($request->input('FirstName'));
                    $LastName           = $mysqli->quote($request->input('LastName'));
                    $NIC                = $mysqli->quote($request->input('NIC'));
                    $IDCard             = $mysqli->quote($request->input('IDCard'));
                    $FirstNameEn        = $mysqli->quote($request->input('FirstNameEn'));
                    $LastNameEn         = $mysqli->quote($request->input('LastNameEn'));
                    $EntrepriseNameAR   = $mysqli->quote($request->input('EntrepriseNameAR'));
                    $EntrepriseNameEN   = $mysqli->quote($request->input('EntrepriseNameEN'));
                    $IDEntreprise       = $mysqli->quote($request->input('IDEntreprise'));
                    $DateStart          = $mysqli->quote($request->input('DateStart'));
                    $DateEnd            = $mysqli->quote($request->input('DateEnd'));
                    $Activity           = $mysqli->quote($request->input('Activity'));
                    $Category           = $mysqli->quote($request->input('Category'));

                    // Construct the SQL update query
                    $query = "UPDATE drivercard 
                            SET 
                            FirstName       = $FirstName, 
                            LastName        = $LastName,
                            FirstNameEn     = $FirstNameEn,
                            LastNameEn      = $LastNameEn,
                            EntrepriseNameAR= $EntrepriseNameAR,                       
                            EntrepriseNameEN= $EntrepriseNameEN,
                            NIC             = $NIC,
                            IDCard          = $IDCard,
                            IDEntreprise    = $IDEntreprise,
                            DateStart       = $DateStart,
                            DateEnd         = $DateEnd,
                            Activity        = $Activity,
                            Category        = $Category
                    
                    WHERE Id =$id";

                    // Execute the query
                    $result = $mysqli->exec($query);
                    
                    // Check if the query was successful
                    if ($result !== false) {
                        return response()->json(['StatusCode' => '1000'], 200);
                    } else {
                        return response()->json(['message' => 'Error updating record']);
                    }
                    // Close the database connection
                    $mysqli = null;
              
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            
            \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::error($e->getMessage());
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Internal Server Error'], 500);
        }            
         
    }
```